# Is it possible to show web push notification on other monitor than the primary display?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, web, web-push

Triggering web-notification on Chrome / Mac OSX, the notification message always shown on the primary display monitor, even if the browser is on a different display.

Is it somehow possible to force the notification to be shown on the same display as the browser window?

**Update**:
I tried multiple ways to display the notification.

Either from a service worker:

```
self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      body,
      icon,
      tag,
    })
```

Or directly using the *Notification* constructor.

In both ways the behaviour is the same.

The simplest way to reproduce it is using [simple push demo](https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/) site.

Comment: How are you showing the notification now?

Comment: @ScottHunter I've updated the question with more details, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is nothing in the API to allow you changing the display the notification is shown.

This is largely dependent on the browser and the current platform as to how the notification is shown (i.e. Browser's custom notification UI vs System UI).

You can always open an issue against the spec with use cases for this: https://github.com/whatwg/notifications

Comment: On Mac specifically you can try turning on chrome://flags#enable-native-notifications That will switch the way notifications are presented so it uses the OS notification center which I believe behaves like you mention.